# Passing multiple parameters to function using settAtribute "onclick" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, parameter-passing

In my code I need to do this:

```
function myFunction() {
        /*more code*/
        let id = 12;
        let name = "something";
        deleteBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "otherFunction("+id+","+name+")");
}
```

In which

```
function otherFunction(id, name){
        /*does other stuf*/
}
```

The issue is, when I run the code and load the html page I get this error:
`SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `deleteBtn.onclick = () => otherFunction(id, name);`

Comment: `deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', () => otherFunction(id, name))`

Comment: That code won't have that effect. I can see it having that effect if you were to change `name` to be something with spaces in it. You should provide a [mcve] and use the live demo feature of the question editor.

Comment: Programatically, generating JavaScript by mashing strings together is a nightmare: It is hard to debug, and has the usual security risks of anything involving `eval`-like processes. Don't do it. Use `addEventListener` and a function instead of a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when it comes to syntax error recheck what you have typed

first i dont see you declare the deleteBtn variable

```
deleteBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "otherFunction("+id+","+name+")");
```

check this code it works

```
document.getElementById('asd').setAttribute('onclick', `otherFunction("${id}","${name}")`);
```

Comment: Using it like this ```.setAttribute('onclick', `otherFunction("${id}","${name}")`);``` got it to work